# How do I copy the contents of a file with a given prefix to another file in restricted write18 enabled mode?

Tags: shell-escape, filesystem-access, l3regex

I know the prefix of a file - and I also know that there exists exactly 1 file with that prefix.

I am running pdftex in restricted write18 enabled mode.

I want to copy the contents of that file to a new file.

How do I go about this? Commands such as `ls`, `touch`, etc. are disabled.

I know how to copy one file from another - the main issue is finding the file that has a matching prefix with the given prefix. How do I find this file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid you can't. The only way to query the file system, under restricted shell-escape, is with `kpsewhich`, which doesn't allow wild cards.

Comment: @egreg Can I list all files in the current directory and iterate over them and print their names?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. If I do `\CatchFileDef{\test}{|"kpsewhich prefix-*}{}`, the macro `\test` returns the unique file name only if `-shell-escape` is enabled.

Comment: It's possible to list files using [`texosquery`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texosquery) but at the moment that's not on the restricted list. It's currently being evaluated by the TeX Live security group to determine whether or not it can be added to the restricted list, so that may be an answer in the future but unfortunately that doesn't help you right now.

Answer (score 2):

You always have the option of running such commands before starting tex, rather than relying on shell-escape.

For example a command line of

```
ls * > filelist.tex; pdflatex myfile
```

would leave the file name of the files in `filelist.tex` so that even if you then generate a prefix from within the `myfile` document you can loop trough the lines of `file.list.tex` using `\read` util you find the required file.

(If the prefix is known in advance you could of course use `ls prefix* > filelist`  which would remove the need for a loop if there is only one file with that prefix)